# TFS SDK 11.0.0 - Cannot save WorkItem - workItem.save() - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, tfs, nullpointerexception

We are using TFS SDK version 11.0.0 connect "TFS: 2015 update 3" to get data and create defect (Bug, Issue, ...) through API. However, we encounter with NullPointerException when creating new defect by using workItem.save() method. Do we use the correct version of the TFS SDK with 'TFS 2-15 update 3'? If yes, why it through exception.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.tfs.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.microsoft.tfs.sdk</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Java Code: NOTE: We check workItem first before saving. Use workItem.isValid() ---> return TRUE

https://github.com/denimgroup/threadfix/blob/2.3/threadfix-main/src/main/java/com/denimgroup/threadfix/service/defects/utils/tfs/TFSClientImpl.java

public String createDefect(String projectName, DefectMetadata metadata, String description) {
    .......
    if (checkItemValues(item)) {
        item.save(); // Throws NullPointerException HERE
    } else {
        LOG.error("Failed to create issue because one or more fields were invalid. "
                + "Check the above logs for more details.");
    }
    ....... 
}

Exception Detail:
WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TFSClientImpl.createDefect(421) | Ran into TFSUnauthorizedException while trying to retrieve products.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fasterxml.aalto.out.ByteXmlWriter.writeAttribute(ByteXmlWriter.java:461)
    at com.fasterxml.aalto.out.StreamWriterBase._writeDefaultNamespace(StreamWriterBase.java:1466)
    at com.fasterxml.aalto.out.NonRepairingStreamWriter.writeDefaultNamespace(NonRepairingStreamWriter.java:107)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.types.DOMAnyContentType.writeElement(DOMAnyContentType.java:306)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.types.DOMAnyContentType.writeElements(DOMAnyContentType.java:274)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.types.DOMAnyContentType.writeAsElement(DOMAnyContentType.java:151)
    at ms.tfs.workitemtracking.clientservices._03._ClientService5Soap_Update.writeAsElement(_ClientService5Soap_Update.java:83)
    at ms.tfs.workitemtracking.clientservices._03._ClientService5Soap12Service$35.writeSOAPRequest(_ClientService5Soap12Service.java:898)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPRequestEntity12.writeRequest(SOAPRequestEntity12.java:94)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.BufferedSOAPRequestEntity.ensureRequestIsBuffered(BufferedSOAPRequestEntity.java:133)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.BufferedSOAPRequestEntity.getContentLength(BufferedSOAPRequestEntity.java:65)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.getRequestContentLength(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:391)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.addContentLengthRequestHeader(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:474)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.addRequestHeaders(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:436)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequestHeaders(HttpMethodBase.java:2596)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2451)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1313)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:508)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:464)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:376)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:588)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:473)
    at ms.tfs.workitemtracking.clientservices._03._ClientService5Soap12Service.update(_ClientService5Soap12Service.java:909)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.update.BaseUpdatePackage.update(BaseUpdatePackage.java:88)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.WorkItemImpl.internalSave(WorkItemImpl.java:673)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.WorkItemImpl.save(WorkItemImpl.java:388)
    at com.denimgroup.threadfix.service.defects.utils.tfs.TFSClientImpl.createDefect(TFSClientImpl.java:411)
    at com.denimgroup.threadfix.service.defects.TFSDefectTracker.createDefect(TFSDefectTracker.java:77)
    at com.denimgroup.threadfix.service.DefectSubmissionServiceImpl.submitDefect(DefectSubmissionServiceImpl.java:42)
    at com.denimgroup.threadfix.service.DefectServiceImpl.createDefect(DefectServiceImpl.java:267)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4695.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.createDefect(Unknown Source)
    at com.denimgroup.threadfix.webapp.controller.DefectsController.onSubmit(DefectsController.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4689.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:867)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:841)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:231)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.denimgroup.threadfix.webapp.filter.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.denimgroup.threadfix.webapp.filter.ClickjackHeaderFilter.doFilter(ClickjackHeaderFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at com.denimgroup.threadfix.webapp.filter.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.denimgroup.threadfix.webapp.filter.EnterpriseFilter.doFilter(EnterpriseFilter.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.denimgroup.threadfix.webapp.filter.CacheBustFilter.doFilter(CacheBustFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: We have the same issue when update Title of existing workItem.

Comment: int workItemId = 6;
            WorkItem itemExisted = client.getWorkItemByID(workItemId);
            if(itemExisted != null && itemExisted.isValid()){
             System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>" + itemExisted.getTitle());
             itemExisted.setTitle("Updated to New Title Bug");
             itemExisted.save(); // It throws NullPointerException after calling this save() method 
            }